# Why am I getting an ‘IndexError: string index out of range’ when I use a concatenated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I use the same code in two separate cases.

Case 1: I open and read a csv file using csv module and implement the code on the data taken from that csv file. The code works fine in this case

Case 2: I use the same code but this time instead of using csv module I use pandas and glob in order to concat 2 csv files(same number of rows and columns) implement the code on the newly concatenated dataframe but get the error ‘IndexError: string index out of range’.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r’Q:\Users\Panagiotis\Betting formula\EPL Seasons’
all_files = glob.glob(path + “/*.csv”)

li = []

for filename in all_files:
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

upsets = 0
non_upsets = 0

starting_bankroll = 100 
wagering_size = 5

bankroll = starting_bankroll

for game in frame:
    home_team = game[2]
    away_team = game[3]

    home_goals = int(game[4])
    away_goals = int(game[5])

    home_odds = float(game[23])
    draw_odds = float(game[24])
    away_odds = float(game[25])

    if home_odds > away_odds:
        if home_goals > away_goals:
            upsets += 1
            bankroll += wagering_size * (home_odds - 1)
        else:
            non_upsets += 1
            bankroll -= wagering_size

ROI = ((bankroll - starting_bankroll) / (wagering_size * (upsets + 
non_upsets))) * 100

print (“There were ‘%s’ upsets out of ‘%s’ total matches” % (upsets, 
upsets + non_upsets))
print (“Starting bankroll = ‘%s’” % (starting_bankroll))
print (“Finishing bankroll = ‘%s’ | ROI = ‘%s’” % (bankroll, ROI))
```

Here is the full error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-27ce3bbe0a95>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('Q:/Users/Panagiotis/Betting formula/csv concatenation formula.py', wdir='Q:/Users/Panagiotis/Betting formula')

  File "Q:\Users\Panagiotis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "Q:\Users\Panagiotis\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "Q:/Users/Panagiotis/Betting formula/csv concatenation formula.py", line 27, in <module>
    away_team = game[3]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is a sample from print(frame):

````
    Div      Date        HomeTeam        AwayTeam  ...  BbAvAHA   PSCH   PSCD   PSCA
0    E0  13-08-16         Burnley         Swansea  ...     1.81   2.79   3.16   2.89
1    E0  13-08-16  Crystal Palace       West Brom  ...     1.85   2.25   3.15   3.86```
````

Comment: sorry, but I dont know why this question got an upvote :) please try to make it shorter and find a more or less _minimal_ example, that reproduces the problem. Just pasting your code sounds like "I'm looking for someone to do my work". Or at least please paste the full error message: this would help us to know where to read to maybe see what might be the problem - sometimes this is enough, even if we cant run the code and reproduce.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. I am new here but also in the world of coding as I just started learning so I apologize for my lack of awareness on how thing operate in general.
As I said I have only began to learn how to code so I do not have other examples where this could be happening also. I tried implementing the code on data from a csv file and thought it would also work on 2 files if I turn them into DataFrames and concatenate them.

Comment: I have included the full error message.

Comment: Please correct your code in `for` loop

Comment: Hello and thank you. I assume you were referring to the indentation? If so, original code has correct indentation, however must have done something wrong while transferring it here. I missed it, thank you for noticing it.

Comment: @PanagiotisVasilakis, next time, you can consider using this instead in indent:
\`\`\`python
your_code
\`\`\`

Comment: @Le Tu Thanh, that is some good input! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, please recheck your `frame` data.

You can check it by `print` out data:

```py
for game in frame:
    print(game, len(game))
```

Pretty sure that at least one `game` will have less than 4 characters inside. E.g. `pyt`, so when you call `game[3]` is `string index out of range`

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Shouldn't the same error then come up when I run the code on a single csv file?

Comment: I'm not sure with your data, but you can consider comment `#` your error code and add my `print` suggestion to figure out exactly your problem.

Comment: I did it, and you are right some columns are less than 4 characters. A lot of them actually.

Comment: Great, now is a different problem, based on your data. Good luck, @PanagiotisVasilakis

Comment: Hmmm i still fail to understand. So the problem is with my data not with the code? Meaning that the rows and columns should be all more than 4 characters long?

Comment: Seem your purpose is writing a stats for football seasons (EPL), please show more with your data (one row example), maybe I can suggest a solution. Or you can focus on your `for` loop: `for game in frame`

Comment: I have been trying to figure it out by myself also by research google but help is always much appreciated! I have edited post with a sample of the data. @ Le Tu Thanh

Comment: I guess, one of your .csv files is not like you expect. Normally the variable `game` is a row from your dataframe, but when it throws the error it is obviously a string.

Check your variables - is `all_files` what you expect or is there some additional file? Did you try to `print(game)` as the answer suggests? you can then see what row it was (the last printed) that caused the error.

Comment: I did try the loop with ```print(game)``` and it returns the columns' headers. I have only two files in the path I use. ```all _files``` is a list with a size of 2, seems correct. I think it has something to do with pandas. I used the same code but instead of reading the csv file with pandas I used csv module ```csv_file = csv.reader(open('epl1617.csv'))
next(csv_file)``` and works fine. The reason I switched to pandas is so that I could use more than one csv files.

Comment: @PanagiotisVasilakis, 
As your expected, each `game` = single row (a list with all information of one match). I'm not sure when you use `print(game)` is the same as you expected. If you can, please give me an example of `print(game)`, the error one as well.

Comment: @LeTuThanh, my fault, as I did not express myself correctly.. When I say ```print(game)``` I was referring to your code ```for game in frame:
    print(game, len(game))```. This code produces every column name and its length, not row. What I included in the post was a sample of the data I am working with. Your code, on the other hand, produces this: ```Div 3
Date 4
HomeTeam 8
AwayTeam 8``` which are the names of every column inside the csv file along which their respective length. So ```game``` = column and the loop aims to iterate every row of a specific column. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @PanagiotisVasilakis, I see, now, you need to split `frame` into a list with each row is an element of that list. Then do the `for game in frame`. Your code will be correct.

Comment: @LeTuThanh, thank you!! you pointed me to the right direction. I created a new variable that turned the dataframe ```frame``` into a list like so ```frame_list = frame.values.tolist()``` and used this variable for my ```for``` loop and it worked! Learned a lot today, thank you!

Comment: @PanagiotisVasilakis, check my answer as a correct one => your problem resolved. Just for save time to anyone else want to help. And you are welcome ;)